# Selecting data in the table with KeyValuePair - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, booleanquery

I'm trying to select the data from key value pair the problem is every time I'm using **AND** it only displaying a one record which is equal to Value column
    but if I tried to use **OR** it giving me wrong return of record. I already did some research but unfortunately I'm not even close to find a solution.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
    SELECT 
    u.userId
    ,u.[Key]
    ,u.[Value]
    ,u.ReportType
    FROM
    OrderItemu 
    WHERE u.userId = 1 AND u.ReportType = 1 AND u.[Value] = '18000981'
```

MyTable:

```
 OrderId     UserId     RowId    Key             Value      ReportType
   1         1           1       OrderNumber     18000981   1
   2         1           1       Item            ToyCar     1
   3         1           1       Price           1000       1
   4         1           2       OrderNumber     18000401   1
   5         1           2       Item            Camera     1
   6         1           2       Price           570        1
```

Result when I'm using **AND** clause:

```
   OrderId   UserId     RowId    Key             Value      ReportType
   1         1           1       OrderNumber     18000981   1
```

Result when I'm using **OR** clause:

```
 OrderId     UserId     RowId    Key             Value      ReportType
   1         1           1       OrderNumber     18000981   1
   2         1           1       Item            ToyCar     1
   3         1           1       Price           1000       1
   4         1           2       OrderNumber     18000401   1
```

The result that I want to achieve:

```
 OrderId     UserId     RowId    Key             Value      ReportType
   1         1           1       OrderNumber     18000981   1
   2         1           1       Item            ToyCar     1
   3         1           1       Price           1000       1
```

Comment: Have you tried some parentheses? It seems that you're not very familiar with boolean logic.

Comment: What is the intention of the table? I don't get it.

Comment: All six rows has userId = 1 and reportType = 1 so your OR version should have included all 6 rows. It is not clear to me what you want to achieve with u.[Value] = '18000981' comparison, it looks like you should ´have `AND rowId = 1` instead

Comment: You may want to use a subquery to get 'rowId' for which you have such value '18000981', then just get all rows with that 'rowId' from the table.

Comment: yes I'm not very familiar with that but I already tried put some parentheses but still not getting the result that I want

Comment: that data is uploaded in excel file so the rowId is not possible because if I have a large data (may cause many rows) it will going to have a different rowId. what I want to achieve get a data by using userId and reporttype with the value of OrderNumber in KeyValuePair

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `exists` subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderItemu oi
WHERE exists
(
    SELECT 
        1
    FROM
        OrderItemu u
    WHERE u.userId = 1 AND u.ReportType = 1 AND u.[Value] = '18000981' and u.RowId = oi.RowId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.userId ,u.[Key] ,u.[Value] ,u.ReportType FROM
OrderItem u 
WHERE u.UserId = 1 AND u.RowId = 1;
```

this query will show what you posted that you want returned( meaning it will show all users with `ID = 1` and all `RowId` = 1 aswell )

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses and both the `key` and `value` column

```
SELECT 
u.userId
,u.[Key]
,u.[Value]
,u.ReportType
FROM
OrderItemu 
WHERE u.userId = 1 
  AND u.ReportType = 1 
  AND (u.[key] = 'OrderNumber' AND u.[Value] = '18000981' OR (u.[key] <> 'OrderNumber'))
```